# Simple proof by induction for $a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^n$

Tags: induction

> If $r\neq 1$, show that $$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^n=\frac{a\left(r^{n+1}-1\right)}{r-1}$$ for any positive integer $n$

I seem to be doing something wrong could somebody tell me what is wrong with my method?

$n=1:$

$$ar^1=\frac{a(r^{1+1}-1)}{r-1}$$
$$ar=\frac{a(r-1)(r+1)}{r-1}$$
$$ar = a(r+1)$$
I can't see anything wrong my working, am i interpreting the question wrong?

Comment: When $n=1$, it should be $a+ar^1$, as when $n=0$, the $L.H.S.$ should be $a$.

Comment: the question says prove for any positive interger of n, does that mean my final proof would read therefore true for all $n\ge1$ or would it conclude true for all $n\ge0$?

Comment: you could see that for $n=0$ the proposition still holds. However you could also try to minus $a$ from both sides. For these kinds of questions I recommend you to try to write it out in summation notation first.

Comment: okay thank you for your help

Comment: Step one: If $a = 0$ you are done, if not cancel it out to make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$ you have to show:

$a+ar=\frac{a(r^{1+1}-1)}{r-1}$

Answer (score 3):

On the left hand side, it should be $a+ar$ instead of $ar$, since you're checking the case for $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

for $n=1$ the term is $a+ar^1=a(1+r)$